# Two NICs on the machine, bind them to the separate interfaces assigned by OS

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi, embedded-linux, nic

I'm currently doing a project with my Raspberry Pi 3 and now I'm having some trouble with it.

I have two NICs (one internal NIC on the SOC and one external NIC) on the RPi and configure the two interfaces (wlan0 and wlan1) to have different functionalities. But since the external NIC CANNOT do the job which the internal NIC can do, I want the NICs and the interfaces assigned by OS to be bound (e.g., internal NIC with wlan0 and external NIC with wlan1) every time I boot up my RPi.

Is there any ways to reach my requirement? Great thanks for any tips or advices!

The OS running on my RPi is Raspbian and the Linux kernel version is 4.1.19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain what you want, but I think you want to ensure that the right name is assigned to each NIC on your Raspberry Pi. If so, you need to set up a `udev` rule that sets the interface name according to the NIC's unique MAC address. You would use `sudo` to edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and make it like this:

```
# interface with MAC address "aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff" will be assigned "eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

# interface with MAC address "mm:nn:oo:pp:qq:rr" will be assigned "eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="mm:nn:oo:pp:qq:rr", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I want!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searching for creating a bond between both your NICs, right?
Don't know about Raspian but in pure Debian is quite simple (did this for a wi-fi USB dongle and a bridged interface in virtualbox without much of a problem):

**`/etc/network/interfaces`**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
gateway 192.168.1.254
netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eth0

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0 
iface bond0 inet dhcp
bond-miimon 100
bond-slaves none
```

Still you need to take care for setting the WPA configuration (in the same file works), here are some URLs that will help there:

- https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1626536

Comment: Not really, I don't want to create a bond between my NICs, instead, I want the NICs to have separated interfaces to act as an network bridge. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You mean you want to route traffic from one NIC to the other? If not and all you need is the persistent name assignation to your NICs then the answer from @Mark Setchell is the right one: use `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`